# A set with a supremum and an infinum inside

Tags: terminology, definition, order-theory

What is the name of a set $A$ that has its infimum $i \in A$ and a supremum $s \in A$?

Examples:

1. $[0,1]$ has a supremum $1$ and an infimum $0$ which are inside $[0,1]$.
2. $\{0,1,2,3\}$ has a supremum $3$ and an infimum $0$, both are inside.
3. $\{0,3\} \cup [1,2]$ has a supremum $3$ and an infimum $0$, both are inside.

Non-examples:

1. Any open interval does not have its infimum and a supremum inside.
2. $\mathbb{N}_0$ has an infimum $0$ which is inside it, but it does not have any supremum that would be inside it, i.e. the first infinite ordinal $\omega \notin \mathbb{N}_0$.

And what is the name of a poset whose all non-empty subsets have an infimum and a supremum inside?

Comment: Compact is the answer to the first question.  And surely the only kind of set that can satisfy the second condition are bounded discrete sets...

Comment: @Frank *Compact* is a topological concept, it doesn't answer the general case for posets. Regarding the second part, it's not true either.

Comment: @GitGud The question is horrifically stated, with general posets only being mentioned in the final sentence. In the rest who knows what $A$ is supposed to be.

Comment: @Frank I added more examples for clarification. Please, do not assume any topology in the examples, the name for the concepts should be topology invariant,e.g. $(0,1)$ could be in $\mathbb{R}$ with the indiscrete topology and therefore compact although it still does not meet the required property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posets whose all non-empty subsets have an infimum and a supremum inside are exactly the finite totally ordered sets. The name of such a poset is "finite chain".

Indeed, let $(D, \leq)$ be a such poset. First, it is totally ordered: for any $x, y \in D$, consider the subset $\{ x, y \}$. Now, since all non-empty subsets have an infimum inside, $(D, \leq)$ is well ordered. In the same way, the dual of $(D, \leq)$ is well ordered. As an exercise, you can check that a well ordered set such that its dual is well ordered is finite.